# Code being redirected to mobile site

Tags: java, http, browser, connection

I am currently getting a webpage using java URL, however it is being redirected to the mobile version of the site.

Is there a way to mimic the browser so I get sent to the main version?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd have to mimic the user agent string in the HTTP header. Can you compare the requests getting sent over the wire? Many tools can help you see this information (I might recommend something like Wireshark.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have your software pretend that it is a PC/Mac browser by explicitly setting the User-Agent string for your request. [Wikipedia info.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

Added: **What is happening**

Some designers look for specific Mobile User-Agent values (eg Android, iPhone, etc) and send just those requests to their mobile sites. By default, they send all other requests to the "regular" web site. I think this is the best technique.

Other designers do the opposite. They send the mobile web site by default and only send the PC/Mac site in response to requests from specific User-Agent strings.